# Android game development - Should I use a framework like AndEngine?

Tags: java, android, frameworks, game-engine

I am going to develop a (relatively) simple game for the Android platform.
It's gonna be 2D-Game (no heavy stuff, maybe simple animations)
I am considering using a framework (like [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/))

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using a framework? (rather than developing from scratch)

Thanks!

Comment: That is entirely dependent on what you are trying to do. If you plan on building a 2d platformer or anything that might utilize sprite sheets or complex hit boxes then by all means use the game engine. No use reinventing the wheel unless you really know what you are doing and have a ton of time. If you are going to do something simpler like 2048 or the good old memory game then game engines will likely be too bulky for your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this can be a broad subject, nonetheless I'll toss in my 2 cents.

There are plenty of advantages using a framework and this applies to many other scenarios. Just think of a framework as a bridge to shorten the path and not have to reinvent the wheel.

A framework will pretty much handle the boring plumbing you would have to do otherwise.
Using a framework will, in most cases, make you code faster and some will probably «force» you to code in a cleaner and more organized fashion. Although this has much more to do with the programmer itself...but there are opinionated frameworks out there that will at least lead you the way.

The biggest disadvantage is not using a framework in itself, but picking the right framework. I think you have to make a few questions before deciding to pick Framework A, B or C such as : Is it sufficientlly mature for my needs? Does it have a good community or vendor support? Is it here to stay? What happens if the framework loses pace or support? Will I be in trouble?

There are other disadvantages of course. You may be putting yourself open to the risk of learning the Framework and neglecting the language behind it. For example, you may know jQuery but it's not liquid that you know javascript. See where I'm going?

Also, you can find yourself shackled by the framework limits. You may not be able to have full control of the code you write or at least not be able to express your code better because the framework it self has tight bounds. In other words, you are forced to respect its limits and work the way it is required. Again, pick the right framework for your needs.

I hope this helped.